# AngularJS object returned from $http - how to get key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In an AngularJS app, I have an object stored in `data` returned from `$http` that looks something like this:

```
[{"var1":"1","var2":"2","var3":"3"}]
```

I want to be able to get the value of `"var2"`.

I thought this would be easy:

```
$scope.myObj = data;

$scope.myVar = $scope.myObj.var2;  //$scope.myvar should "2"
```

Instead, $scope.myObj returns `undefined`

how can I access the value of var2?

Comment: If $scope.myObj returns undefined, you DONT have the data yet. Paste the code for help.

Comment: Seems like `data` is array, if it is always of size 1 array then do `$scope.myObj = data[0]`

Comment: @user013948 it's not empty. `console.log($scope.myvar)` shows `[object Object]` and, in HTML, `{{myVar}}` displays `[{"var1":"1","var2":"2","var3":"3"}]`

Comment: Try  $scope.myVar.var2

Comment: @PSL Bingo! It was an array, even though `angular.isObject()` returned `true`. Please enter this as an answer and I will mark it as CORRECT!!

Comment: @lilbiscuit Sure added as answer. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in  your case data is an array. And if it is always of size -1 array just do:

```
$scope.myObj = data[0]; //Add any necessary null checks
```

Modify your logic accordingly by looping through the array if it is of size > 1.

`angular.isObject()` returns true because array is also an object.

You can use `angular.isArray(obj)` before checking `isObject` to make sure you filter out arrays as is. If you get mixed data i.e sometimes object, sometimes array of size-1 with the same object you could also do:- `$scope.myObj = [].concat(data)[0]`.